# Default styles overriding theme.json

Tags: bug, theme.json

I'm going through [Complete WordPress Developer Course 2023 - Plugins & Themes](https://www.udemy.com/course/wordpress-development-create-wordpress-themes-and-plugins)
 course.

With:

- PHP: 8.19
- Web Server: nginx
- WP: 6.2
- MySQL: 8.0.16

following theme.json

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schemas.wp.org/trunk/theme.json",
    "version": 2,
    "settings": {
        "color": {
            "defaultPalette": false,
            "palette": [
                {
                    "slug": "u-primary",
                    "color": "rgb(239 68 68)",
                    "name": "Udemy Primary"
                }
            ],
            "link": true,
            "custom": true
        }
    },
    "styles": {
        "elements": {
            "link": {
                "color": {
                    "text": "var(--wp--preset--color--u-primary)"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and templates\index.html

```
<!-- wp:site-title /-->
```

The theme.json anchor color in title is being overridden by default WP style

[image: Image shows that theme.json link is overriden by .wp-block-site-title a style]

As you can see above the specificity of an anchor style created from theme.json
is very weak. When i tried to fix my issue with adding bad, old `!important` to my style
it resulted in coloring the admin bar links

[image]

How to create the anchor style correctly or did i find a bug?